# FileSize referenced in PHP Post is unusually high

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, php, centos, http

CentOS 5.x | Apache 2

I'm setting up an instance of w2box on my web server.  It basically uses a standard perl script (upload.cgi) to store a file being posted.

As a test, I'm trying to upload an ubuntu ISO (716 MB).  However, when I examine the apache access logs I see this:

-  [07/Jul/2010:03:08:44 +0400] "POST /upload.cgi?sid=a4984a5sdkfjhsdkfhsdk68ef1c25f5931&maxsize=**1073741824** HTTP/1.1" 500 636

My PHP limits are:

post_max_size 1100M

memory_limit 1200M

My question though is, why is the maxsize so high in the POST url? Does the web browser do some extra encoding that bloats the size of data?

If I want to support uploads of up to 1 GB, what would my php memory values need to be?

-M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That "maxsize" parameter in the URL doesn't seem to be related to either PHP or Apache.

It's probably a value that your PHP application is expecting. If it's specified in bytes, it means 1024MB.

Comment: Thanks Guys.  You're right.  It was an additional parameter in the upload.cgi script. Thanks!